# Generate Date List of Lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to generate a list of lists which each sublist containing a date between two dates. I am eventually going to append values to each sublist.

My code:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

def date_increments(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta

my_dates = []
row=0
for result in date_increments(date(2014, 10, 10), date(2014, 10, 12), timedelta(days=1)):
    my_dates[row][0] = result
    row += 1

print my_dates
```

Error:

```
my_dates[row][0] = result
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Desired output:

```
[[date(2014, 10, 10)],[date(2014, 10, 11)],[date(2014, 10, 12)]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `append`:

```
my_dates.append([result])
```

You don't even need to use `row`.

Also, use:

```
while curr <= end:
```

in order to have `end` in the final list.

And for an even shorter solution, use:

```
my_dates = [[res] for res in date_increments(date(2014, 10, 10), date(2014, 10, 12), timedelta(days=1))]
```